# DFT-Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, dft

I'm trying to create a Discrete-Fourier-Transformation Matrix in R and I don't know if it is right.

I shall create a matrix that looks like: 1/sqrt(N) * [w^(m*n)] for n,m in [0:N-1] for w = exp(-2*pi*i/N) as in ([Wikipedia->DFT-Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix))

So I tried:

```
DFT.matrix <- function (N) {

   w <- exp(-2*pi*1i/N)

   row <- vector()
   for (n in seq(0,N-1,1)) 
      for (m in seq(0,N-1,1)) 
         row <- c(row, w^(m*n))

   dft_matrix = (1/sqrt(N))*matrix(row, N, byrow=TRUE)
   return (dft_matrix)
}
```

I haven't built in the complex i, because I don't no how to implement.
Can you help me to realize this function?

Comment: I changed: w <- exp(-2*pi/N)
To: w <- exp(-2*pi*1i/N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
N  <- 3
w <- exp(-2*pi*1i/N)
outer(0:(N-1), 0:(N-1), function(i, j) w^(i*j)) / sqrt(N)
#             [,1]            [,2]            [,3]
#[1,] 0.5773503+0i  0.5773503+0.0i  0.5773503+0.0i
#[2,] 0.5773503+0i -0.2886751-0.5i -0.2886751+0.5i
#[3,] 0.5773503+0i -0.2886751+0.5i -0.2886751-0.5i
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Your function is more R-Style than mine but does the same. I'm coming from C/C++. So please be patient.